# Ubuntu 17.10,Can not type in chinese with ibus in third party apps

Tags: 17.10, ibus

version:

> ubuntu: 17.10
>
> ibus : 1.5.14
>
> ibus-pinyin

I can type in chinese on the terminal and other default apps.But not third party apps like vscode,chrome,etc.